# Sending Emails C#

Tags: .net, email

I am writing a application which need to open a new mail dialog, upon clicking on a button on it. Application users uses different mail clients like MS Outlook, Thunder Bird, etc...

Application should open a new mail dialog filled with information passed by my application, like **TO**, **BCC**, **Subject** and **Body** sometimes with **attachments**.

And there is a requirement to set the **from** address too.

Most important thing is mail format should be in **HTML**

Comment: Thank you for replies, I just want to open a new mail dialog with given values, for fields like "from", "to", etc... exactly similar to action "mailto:" in HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to send a mail programmatically in c#, C# is coming with "using System.Net.Mail" namespace. SmtpClient and MailMessage classes can do the work for you to explicitly send a mail configured with CC and BB and subjects settings by you.. .
For e.g;

```
//instance of mail message
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

                //create instance of smtpclient
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

                smtp.EnableSsl = true;

                //recipient address
                mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(userid));

                //Formatted mail body
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                string st = ""; 
st += "<HTML><BODY>";
                        st += "<span style='font-family: Verdana; font-size: 9pt'>";
                        st += "Dear Sir/Madam,<br/><br/>";
                        st += "We refer to your request for reseting your login password.";
                        st += "Please take note of your Login Password, as you need them every time you login.<br/><br/>";
                        st += "<b>Email/Userid: " + userid + "</b><br/>";
                        st += "<b>Password: " + password + "</b><br/><br/>";
                        st += "Regards</br>";
                        st += "XYZ Team";
                        st += "</span><br />";
                        st += "</HTML></BODY>";         
                        mail.Body = st;

                //send mail via smtp client
                smtp.Send(mail);
```

Following is the Configuration settings for SMTP client that need to be done in the APP.config:

```
> <system.net>
>     <mailSettings> <smtp from="">
>         <network host="" port="" userName="" password=""
> defaultCredentials="false" />
>       </smtp>  </mailSettings>   </system.net>
```

Note: you can define these values via code as well.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This even let you add an attachment:
Attachment attach = new Attachment("c:\filename.txt");
                mail.Attachments.Add(attach);

Comment: Sorry I misunderstand your question, and replied only how to send mail .. your issue is configuring new outlook mail the way you want. (mail send task will be done by outlook itself). For that you can access following link, that I found for you:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsto/thread/64f5ba58-5dd0-48e7-a706-a2de214f5be9
Or
you can create an object of outlook application.
Outlook.Application objOutlk = new Outlook.Application();
and create its new item i.e.
objMail = objOutlk.CreateItem(olMailItem);
now you can configure this objMail..

Comment: Thank you for replies, I just want to open a new mail dialog with given values, for fields like "from", "to", etc... exactly similar to action "mailto:" in html

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to below article for more information about mailto: protocol sytax

http://www.ianr.unl.edu/internet/mailto.html

> The MailTo command can do more than
>   enter a single e-mail address in the
>   "Send To" field while activating your
>   e-mail program. It can also: Feature
>   Syntax  Address message to multiple
>   recipients  ,   (comma separating
>   e-mail addresses)  Add entry in the
>   "Subject" field  subject=Subject Field
>   Text  Add entry in the "Copy To" or
>   "CC" field  cc=id@internet.node  Add
>   entry in the "Blind Copy To" or "BCC"
>   field  bcc=id@internet.node  Add entry
>   in the "Body" field  body=Your message
>   here Within the body use "%0A" for a
>   new line, use "%0A%0A" for a new line
>   preceded by a blank line (paragraph),
>   see example below.
>
> Notes:
>
> " " (beginning and ending double
>   quotes) are necessary if any spaces
>   are used
>
> Mailto parameter should be preceded by
>   "?" for the first or only parameter
>   and "&" for second and subsequent
>   parameter.

I doubt about Attachments. I dont think you can apply attachments with mailto links. But still lets see if some one knows about this.

Comment: Here the issue it "Mailto:" wont support HTML format mails, and body size is limited to 255 chars, so I can't use it :(

Comment: And it also will not allow you to add Attachments.. Sorry me too. But according to your requirement, IMHO, mailto: is the best available solution or you should popup your own Mail sender.

Answer (score 0):

we are using this tool http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/CMapiEx.aspx.

Also check out that [How do I popup the compose / create mail dialog using the user's default email client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450115/how-do-i-popup-the-compose-create-mail-dialog-using-the-users-default-email-cl)

Answer (score 0):

So the question is a little confusing: does the application need to automate Outlook and Thunderbird or do you need to send email using C# to *clients* that will use Outlook and Thunderbird?

If you need to automate the third-party applications then look to VBA for Outlook. (I'm not sure that Thunderbird can be automated in this way as I don't believe it has an externally visible macro language. But given that the corollary of [Zawinski's Law of Software Envelopment](http://catb.org/jargon/html/Z/Zawinskis-Law.html) is that every application gets a macro language to send email I may be wrong.)

If you want to send mail from a C# application take a look at the [MailMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx) (MSDN) component. This should do everything you need. You'll need to configure it appropriately to send mail in the MIME format `text/html`: MSDN has an example of how to do this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.alternateviews.aspx) that also includes alternate views for users that can't or won't read HTML mail.

Comment: I just want to pop up a new mail dialog of the default mail client. Not automate, user will sent it manually.