# Send Picturebox Image to your default email

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, email

In my form, I have a picturebox that contains an image. I'm trying to figure out how to put the image from my picturebox as an attachment and in the body of my default email.

**This is what I have so far:**

This opens up my default email which is outlook but does not attach or paste the picture in the body.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       var url = "mailto:emailnameu@domain.com&SUBJECT=My Subject&body="+pictureBox1.Image+"&attachment=" + pictureBox1.Image;
       System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);
    }
```

This is what happens when I add this line in my variable `&body="+pictureBox1.Image+` It does not paste the picture in the body but writes `System.Drawing.Bitmap`

[image]

Comment: Hi @vasek this doesn't talk about using smtp server. I'm talking about how to do it with your default email

Comment: Sorry, picked wrong link on mobile. This is correct one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450115/how-do-i-popup-the-compose-create-mail-dialog-using-the-users-default-email-c

Comment: Hi @vasek no problem, but this link doesn't provide a solution to this particular issue

Answer (score 1):

You can't send image content on the body using mailto, its said [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068)

> The special  "body" indicates that the associated 
> is the body of the message.  The "body" field value is intended to
> contain the content for the first text/plain body part of the
> message.  The "body" pseudo header field is primarily intended for
> the generation of short text messages for automatic processing (such
> as "subscribe" messages for mailing lists), not for general MIME
> bodies.

Also, attachments isn't officially supported for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send image using `mailto:`, as other answers and comments say. However there is a working way how to send image from PictureBox.

Basic idea is taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25586282/611117). That solution only creates `.eml` file that is opened by associated application.

So you only need to save your PictureBox content and send it as attachment:

```
string tempEmail = Path.ChangeExtension(Path.GetTempFileName(), "eml");
string tempImage = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "Attachment.jpg");

pictureBox1.Image.Save(tempImage, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

var mailMessage = new MailMessage("from@domain.com", "to@domain.com", "Subject here", "Body text here");
mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(tempImage));
mailMessage.Save(tempEmail);

Process.Start(tempEmail);
```

Note you should also consider some cleanup after email client is closed.