# Is it possible to have access to MS Outlook contacts through PHP Code?

Tags: php, outlook

Is it possible to have access to MS Outlook contacts through PHP Code?

Comment: Are you on about parsing a .PST file?

Comment: Are the Outlook installation and the PHP script running on the same machine? Is it just a standalone Outlook, or are the contacts part of an Exchange/Active Directory/LDAP server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're looking for the harder case (accessing an existing Exchange server), here's a blog post from someone who claims to have done it: http://andrewparisio.blogspot.com/2010/11/asterisk-php-and-exchange-web-services.html

I found this link on a  [previous SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588/best-way-to-access-exchange-using-php), and the discussion there may be helpful to you as well.