# How can I retrieve groups and contacts from microsoft exchange server using php?

Tags: php, exchange-server

I need to retrieve **using php** all the accounts informations (like name - email - group..), managed by a specific microsoft exchange server for use into my application.

Which is the best way to perform this job?

Mirco

Comment: Potential duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588/best-way-to-access-exchange-using-php) post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the new version of Exchange Server has a web services interface that you could access to retrieve information.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204119(v=exchg.140).aspx